# How to use java reflection to return a Collection that contains something other then Objects

Tags: java, list, generics, reflection, collections

So my problem is that im currently trying to use java's reflection to traverse a tree like structure. The problem is the only thing i know about each structure is that it can contain one of three things. Strings (the leaf's) Other Objects, Or Lists of other objects. Using reflection i want to do a DFS of the tree until i find a node that im looking for. My problem seems to be that when i use reflection to get a field that happens to be of type List i get back List and i am unable to down cast the the correct type. here are some samples i have tried.

Using Fields

```
Object returnObj = new Object();
Field field = object.getClass().getDeclaredField(fieldClassName);   
field.setAccessible(true);
List<DistributionPartnerRoleType> test = (List<DistributionPartnerRoleType>) field.get(object);
```

And using Methods

```
    String methodName = "get" + Character.toUpperCase(fieldClassName.charAt(0)) + fieldClassName.substring(1);
    Method[] getters = object.getClass().getMethods();
    Method getter = getMethod(getters, methodName);
    Type returnType = getter.getGenericReturnType();
    if(returnType instanceof ParameterizedType){
        Type actualType = ((ParameterizedType) returnType).getActualTypeArguments()[0];
        Class actualClass = (Class) actualType;
        returnObj = getter.invoke(object, null);
        List<Object> newList = new ArrayList<Object>();
        for(Object obj : (List<Object>)returnObj){
              newList.add(actualClass.cast(obj));
        }
        returnObj = newList;
    }
```

Im aware that the problem is that the objects are truly of type Object but the function and fields are explicitly of type List as declared in the code

```
protected List<DistributionPartnerRoleType> distributionPartnerRole;

public List<DistributionPartnerRoleType> getDistributionPartnerRole() {
    if (distributionPartnerRole == null) {
        distributionPartnerRole = new ArrayList<DistributionPartnerRoleType>();
    }
    return this.distributionPartnerRole;
}
```

If anyone knows of a solution for this problem that would be great, Or if i need to go about a different method other then reflection.

To sum up my problem. Invoke is returning a List But the objects inside the list are not actually of the type this function returns they are of type java.lang.Object Is there any way to get around this or is dynamic access of the lists objects not possible?

Comment: If you're using reflection, you'll need to cast the `List` into the list of whatever type you actually expect.  There isn't actually any difference between a `List<Object>` and a `List<Foo>`.  You'll just need to cast.

Comment: newList.add(actualClass.cast(obj))
When i go to cast the objects im getting a class cast exception because the invoke returned Actual Objects objects not DistributionPartnerRoleType objects. While i can cast the list to what ever i want the objects inside them remain of type Object

Comment: Then you're calling the wrong method, or doing something else wrong. Reflection doesn't produce that sort of problem.  Check that when you call the _exact same method_ without reflection, you get actual `DistributionPartnerRoleType` objects, not just `Object`s.

Comment: Well i tried that and it is returning that Objects. There must be a problem somewhere else. Thanks ill have to dive deeper to see where this is happening. This class is used in many other places and i have no problem like this one. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think use of reflection is a good idea in this case. In my view there are very few appropriate use cases. It's often a sign that you need to rethink your approach.

In this case I suggest you look at the [Visitor design pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern). The visitor itself can include the logic for a depth-first search as well as dealing with the various types of data in the nodes.

In your case the pattern might look something like:

```
interface Node {
    void accept(NodeVisitor visitor);
}

class StringNode implements Node {
    public String getValue();

    public void accept(NodeVisitor visitor) {
        visitor.visit(this);
    }
}

class IntegerNode implements Node {
    public int geValue();

    public void accept(NodeVisitor visitor) {
        visitor.visit(this);
    }
}

class CompositeNode implements Node {
    public void forEachChild(Consumer<Node> action);

    public void accept(NodeVisitor visitor) {
        visitor.visit(this);
    }
}

interface NodeVisitor {
    default void visit(StringNode node) {}
    default void visit(IntegerNode node) {}
    default void visit(CompositeNode node) {}
}
```

Now your search algorithm might look like:

```
class IntegerSearch implements NodeVisitor {
    private final int target;
    private final List<IntegerNode> results = new ArrayList<>();

    void visit(IntegerNode node) {
        if (node.getValue() == target)
            results.add(node);
        }
    }

    void visit(CompositeNode node) {
        node.forEachChild(child -> child.accept(this));
    }
}
```

No reflection, casting or other dodgy idioms!

This might not exactly match your case (e.g. perhaps the nodes with values are also composites?) but hopefully you see the general pattern for avoiding reflection.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but due to time and money there is just no way i can rewrite our code base to handle this sort of solution.  The existing class structure cant be changed and using reflection seems like the most simple solution

Comment: Ah the traditional developer's false economy: "we can't afford to make our code more readable and maintainable." For code that will be used once and then thrown out, sure. But in a long career I have never once seen that calculation pay off in the longer term.

Answer (score 0):

There is a deeper problem here, As stated by Louis Wasserman, reflection should not be causing this and there seems to be a problem with my code in another location.